# tensorflow not found in virtual enivironment and anaconda prompt

Tags: tensorflow, virtual, environment

I had installed tensorflow in anaconda command prompt and run my program from it, but it state:

> no module named tensorflow is found.

I tried in virtual environment too. I'm able to install in virtual environment yet i get same error message.

Mine is **python 3.7** and **64 bit** version
running through anaconda prompt

I'm not able to install using pip install tensorflow in anaconda prompt

but only through 
`python -m pip install --upgrade` https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

but pip install tensorflow working in virtual environment

attached the screenshots below(anaconda prompt and virtual env)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow has not yet been officially released for python 3.7, setup a new Conda environment with python 3.6 and use it for now.

You can use this to create a new environment 
`conda create --name py36 python=3.6`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tensorflow working in new environment with python 3.6.